# Not able to convert checkpoint models to Tensorflow graph proto

Tags: python, tensorflow

**System Information:**

- Windows 10
- Tensorflow version: 1.10.0 (Installed through pip)
- I do not have a GPU on my system.

I created my own dataset of ~100 images with 1 class and ran the legacy/train.py script for the training. I got the below checkpoint files:

```
model.ckpt-649.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-649.index
model.ckpt-649.meta
```

However, I get the below error when I run the export_inference_graph.py file.

> python .\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py --input_type
>   image_tensor --pipeline_config_path
>   .\object_detection\training\ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
>   --trained_checkpoint_prefix .\object_detection\training\model.ckpt-649.index --output_directory
>   .\object_detection\trained-inference-graphs

I ultimately want to use the .pb file to evaluate the model using the code provided by tensorflow.

Logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Tensor name "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases" not found in checkpoint fil
es .\object_detection\training\model.ckpt-649.index
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2
/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1725, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Tensor name "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases" not found in checkpoint fil
es .\object_detection\training\model.ckpt-649.index
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2
/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 153, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 149, in main
    write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 405, in export_inference_graph
    write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 334, in _export_inference_graph
    trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 241, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
    tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def, name='')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 442, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 234, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3289, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3289, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3180, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases" not found in checkpoint files .\object_de
tection\training\model.ckpt-649.index
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2
/shape_and_slices)]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1737, in restore
    checkpointable.OBJECT_GRAPH_PROTO_KEY)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 348, in get_tensor
    status)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: _CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH not found in checkpoint file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 153, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 149, in main
    write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 405, in export_inference_graph
    write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 334, in _export_inference_graph
    trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 245, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1743, in restore
    err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing")
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Origin
al error:

Tensor name "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases" not found in checkpoint files .\object_detection\training\model.ckpt-649.index
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2
/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 153, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\object_detection\export_inference_graph.py", line 149, in main
    write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 405, in export_inference_graph
    write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 334, in _export_inference_graph
    trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 241, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
    tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def, name='')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 442, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 234, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3289, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3289, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3180, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Tensor name "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases" not found in checkpoint files .\object_detection\training\model.ckpt-649.index
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2
/shape_and_slices)]]
```